# Do not match white space if it is the last character of the string or the next group does not match?

Tags: regex

I have a Regex that is used to recognise tooth, The regex is as follow:

```
/((U|L)(R|L)[0-8a-eA-E](\s|\/|-|_)?((M|O|D|I|B|P|L)+)?)/gi
```

It should (and does) match the following:

UR7

UR7 MOD

UR5-MOD

The problem is, The last part (after the UR and the number) are optional so it could be that they are not entered, which is fine however unfortunately the optional space is still being matched so for example:

```
UR7
```

(Please notice the space after the UR7) matches the space as well ..

I can see two ways to tackle this:

1. Only match this group (\s|/|-|_) if the next group matches?
   or
2. Do not match the group (\s|/|-|_) if it is the last character of a match.

Could anyone please help me to achieve this?

So the desired behaviour is for all the above matches to match but for a UR7 with a space after to match only the UR7 and not the space!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you intend to stop at 8? /((U|L)(R|L)[0-8a-eA-E](\s|\/|-|_)?((M|O|D|I|B|P|L)+)?)/gi

Comment: @Tony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_notation#Letters_and_numbers_system seems to confirm that human teeth only go to 8.

Comment: ... Though we apparently ought to exclude zero.

Comment: Haha well it depends on the system used but there are 32 teeth. You're right though about excluding the 0!!

Comment: Haha good catch on the 0! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the separator as tolerated only when it is followed by something more.

I have also refactored to use character classes for single characters, as that is typically more efficient.

```
/[UL][RL][0-8a-eA-E]((\s|[-\/_])?[MODIBPL]+)?/gi
```